# setEmptyView not working in custom ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom ListView which is one of the tabs of a viewPager.

```
public class MyListView extends ListView
```

I instantiate an object of my class and setEmptyView using

```
ListView myList = new MyListView(context);
View emptyView = myLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mylist_empty_view, null);
myList.setEmptyView(emptyView);
myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

However the emptyView never shows up, does not have a parent (which ideally should be the listview) and I cannot see it in the hierarchyViewer. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

`AdapterView` only manages the visibility of `emptyView`. If the adapter is empty or `null`, the visibility of the `ListView` will be `GONE` while `emptyView` is `VISIBLE`, but to make it show up, you need to add it to the layout yourself.

Just try using this layout

```
FrameLayout myLayout = new FrameLayout(context);
myLayout.addView(myList);
myLayout.addView(emptyView);
```

instead of `myList` directly.

Comment: That isn't exactly how things should be right. What is the point to the setEmptyView in the ListView then? I don't want to add a frameLayout. I want the ListView to be a child of a ViewPager, the emptyView to be a child of the listview.

Comment: @user2759617 for doing so you need to implement your own Adapter. There you can show a View if there's not data. ListView doesn't manage other Views than the ones created by the Adapter itself.

Comment: I do have my own adapter. But the general flow should be, I set the adapter, set the empty view on the listView and then if the adapter is empty, the listview makes the empty view visible. Otherwise it should make it hidden. This should be the general flow. Not sure why it is not working with a view pager.

Comment: @user2759617 it almost works like you describe it. You just need to attach the View to another layout. The AdapterView only layouts the Views provided by the Adapter. But maybe the ViewPager has its own way to manage its Views and setting the visibility doesn't do anything. What's wrong with the FrameLayout?